# Is there a GRUB 2 Source Code Map?

Tags: grub

I have been studying the GRUB 2 Bootloader source code but I haven’t been able to find in the documentation a map describing the general purpose of each source code files and how they relate to each other. Also the few articles I have found googling about the subject are for legacy versions of GRUB.

Obviously if I keep reading the code I will eventually do my own map. However I would like to know if there is any official or unofficial map.

PD: If my question is unclear or inappropriate please let me know and I will improve it ASAP!

Comment: Do you mean a high-level overview, or a complete mapping?

Comment: I mean a complete files mapping. Of course a high-level overview that includes the main file names could be useful if is based on GRUB 2 and not on legacy.

Comment: GRUB specific forums would probably be more effective. If you want details about source code, you should talk to a developer. Probably the most effective way of doing so it to hop on IRC, at least initially.

Comment: @artificer, did you ever find that "source code map"?